# Brand identity and naming for your web/programming project

Tags: language-agnostic

Not sure if this belongs on SO but nonetheless it involves web dev/programming...

I think i'm pretty creative in general but when it comes to naming something giving its own identity im totally short of any inspiration..or rather incapable of providing something thats catchy.(Like Twitter and tweets etc)

So you've got this great idea, maybe its an app(lication - depending on how much of an apple fanboy you are) or a website. In my opinion about 71% of the success is down to the brand name(something catchy)/identity, regardless of how good the actual application is.

Any idea where to begin with something like that & How do you get inspiration for something like this?

Comment: "In my opinion about 70% of the success is down to the brand name..." You are wrong.

Comment: Doesn't this belong on stackexchange's "programmers" not stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're a programmer ... so by default you aren't built to think like an advertisement exec.

Best practice? Sound it out verbally, make sure it has a ring to it. Then bounce the name(s) off of about 10 people that are not very computer savvy and let them pick the best one.

If someone proposed "Twitter" as a name to me I would have mocked it. Some of my less-tech-savvy peers would have probably liked it because it has a ring to it and reminds them of Bambi.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to talk to a graphic designer, this is there bag, (I should know).

They can then create a whole image/corporate identity for you. A good brand really does come from a good designer.

The name doesn't matter to a certain degree, take 'ebay' it doesn't relate to what the company are selling, but after a good marketing push and brand it's now a house-hold name. It helps to get a good idea of who you are marketing it the product at, and doing a little research so you know your target market and what they do/like wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: thanks! and in relation to ebay, true.. however its something like that thats simple to remember, catchy as opposed to someOtherAuctionSite.com

Comment: What we sometime do with clients is get them to choose two words completely at random, "blue pencil" "Massive Mouse" "Pink Book" etc. Gets you thinking slightly out side the box. Once you have a catchy name, even if it doesn't relate tot he subject matter you can take it further with the brand